# no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that T conforms to Comparable<? super T>

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Below is a stripped down version of my implementation structure. Just like how I have a class BGroup that performs operations on individual B classes and extends class A, I have a class CGroup that performs individual operations on individual C classes and extends Class A, and so on and so forth. However at the super.sort() method, I get a compilation error at `Collections.sort(this.list)` that states:

`reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that T conforms to Comparable<? super T>`

I am unsure how to resolve this error. I don't understand specifically what `Comparable<? super T>` means. Any help is appreciated.

```
public abstract class A <T> {
     private List<T> list;

    public A() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    //Protected methods accessible to class GroubB that act upon this.list
    .
    .
    .
    protected void sort() {
        Collections.sort(this.list);
    }

    protected void insertElement(T t) {
        this.list.add(t);  
    }
}

public final class BGroup extends A <GroupB> {
    public B() {
        super();
    }

    public void addB(B b) {
        super.insertElement(b);
        super.sort();        
    }

    //Getter and Setter methods that act upon Generic T
    .
    .
    .
}

public final class B implements Comparable<B> {
    private LocalDate date;

    public Expense(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() { return date; }
    
    public void setDate (LocalDate date) { this.date = date; }
    

    @Override
    public int compareTo(B that) {
        return this.getDate().compareTo(that.getDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: `T` doesn't extend `Comparable`.

Comment: And what's `GroupB`? Please edit your question to be a complete example, which compiles, except for that single error.

Comment: I see that `BGroup` ensures `T` is comparable (assuming `GroupB = B`), but that doesn't help `A`. What would you expect to happen if I create a `class C extends A<Object>` and tried to sort? You need to declare `T extends Comparable<T>` if you want to guarantee `T` is sortable.

Comment: @shmosel can you explain how this is different than writing  Class A<T> implements Comparable<T>

Comment: `public abstract class A<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I've added a clarification to my question

Comment: @J_code How is it the same? You're trying to sort instances of `T`, not `A`.

Comment: @J_code `Class A<T> implements Comparable<T>` means that instances of `A` are comparable to instances of `T`, which is not what you want. You want the instances of `T` to be comparable with themselves, so code `Class A<T extends Comparable<T>>`